# Error when executing spring sample for camunda 8 platform

Tags: java, spring, camunda

I am a newbie trying to execute [the spring sample for camunda 8 platform](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-platform-get-started/tree/main/spring). I have the camunda 8 platform running locally using [this docker-compose](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-platform/blob/main/docker-compose-core.yaml) file. Attached is the screenshot of the local docker ps command.

After cloning the project I have renamed the application.local.properties to application.properties so that the application could connect to the local zeebe cluster (and I deleted the existing application.properties that contained cloud properties) but when I execute the ProcessApplication class I get an error "org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean ‘zeebeClientLifecycle’

Below is the detailed error trace. I am kind of surprised that an out-of-the-box example isn't working out. Could someone guide me on troubleshooting this further?

```java
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'zeebeClientLifecycle'; nested exception is io.camunda.zeebe.client.api.command.ClientStatusException
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$$Lambda$1501/0x0000000000000000.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at io.camunda.getstarted.ProcessApplication.main(ProcessApplication.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: io.camunda.zeebe.client.api.command.ClientStatusException: null
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.ZeebeClientFutureImpl.transformExecutionException(ZeebeClientFutureImpl.java:93) ~[zeebe-client-java-8.0.2.jar:8.0.2]
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.ZeebeClientFutureImpl.join(ZeebeClientFutureImpl.java:50) ~[zeebe-client-java-8.0.2.jar:8.0.2]
    at io.camunda.zeebe.spring.client.config.processor.DeploymentPostProcessor.lambda$apply$6(DeploymentPostProcessor.java:73) ~[spring-zeebe-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
    at io.camunda.zeebe.spring.client.config.processor.DeploymentPostProcessor$$Lambda$330/0x0000000068dff770.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at io.camunda.zeebe.spring.client.ZeebeClientLifecycle.lambda$start$0(ZeebeClientLifecycle.java:45) ~[spring-zeebe-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
    at io.camunda.zeebe.spring.client.ZeebeClientLifecycle$$Lambda$397/0x0000000068c7e890.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at io.camunda.zeebe.spring.client.ZeebeClientLifecycle.start(ZeebeClientLifecycle.java:45) ~[spring-zeebe-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999) ~[na:na]
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.ZeebeClientFutureImpl.join(ZeebeClientFutureImpl.java:48) ~[zeebe-client-java-8.0.2.jar:8.0.2]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED
    at io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException.fillInStackTrace(StatusRuntimeException.java:68) ~[grpc-api-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException.<init>(StatusRuntimeException.java:58) ~[grpc-api-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException.<init>(StatusRuntimeException.java:50) ~[grpc-api-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535) ~[grpc-api-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:478) ~[grpc-stub-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:463) ~[grpc-core-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:427) ~[grpc-core-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:460) ~[grpc-core-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:562) ~[grpc-core-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:70) ~[grpc-core-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:743) ~[grpc-core-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:722) ~[grpc-core-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133) ~[grpc-core-1.45.1.jar:1.45.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed while requesting access token with status code 404 and message Not Found.
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.oauth.OAuthCredentialsProvider.fetchCredentials(OAuthCredentialsProvider.java:183) ~[zeebe-client-java-8.0.2.jar:8.0.2]
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.oauth.OAuthCredentialsProvider.refreshCredentials(OAuthCredentialsProvider.java:132) ~[zeebe-client-java-8.0.2.jar:8.0.2]
```

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved after renaming the application.properties file to application.yaml file. The application started successfully. Infact after the application started I could revert back to properties from yaml and it still worked.

Strange issue.